# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date

Tags: python, django

In model, I have a property

```
accepted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I save it

```
from datetime import datetime

Entry.objects.last().accepted_at = datetime.now()
```

I'm trying to know if is accepted before 30 minutes

```
from datetime import datetime


if (datetime.now() - Entry.objects.last().accepted_at).total_seconds() > 1800:
    return True
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you cannot subtract a `datetime.datetime` from a `datetime.date`. I would first debug to double check that `Entry.objects.last().accepted_at` is, in fact, a `datetime.datetime` type. You can do this with a simple:

```py
print( type(Entry.objects.last().accepted_at) == datetime )
```

or just check the type:

```py
print( type(Entry.objects.last().accepted_at) )
```

If this doesn't equal `True` then you know it is not a `datetime`.

Also for checking if the accepted time is *smaller* than 30 minutes you should alter your code just a bit. Make sure the elapsed time is smaller than or equal (<=) to the minutes before expiration:

```py
from datetime import datetime

minutesBeforeExpiration = 30
secondsPerMin = 60

if (datetime.now() - Entry.objects.last().accepted_at).total_seconds() <= (minutesBeforeExpiration * secondsPerMin):
    return True
```